# Oblique EPI in afni

Tags: fmri, data, signal-processing

It is my very first time with afni and I am having problems with the creation of the afni dataset from dicom images.

I runned:

```
Dimon -infile_prefix IM -gert_create_dataset
```

and I got this error:

```
Dimon version 4.18 (November 9, 2016) running, use <ctrl-c> to quit...

-- scanning for first volume
++ Data detected to be oblique
** cannot find a volume in 4400 image files
   (max allowable = 3000, see -max_images)
```

As I want to keep my EPI dataset oblique I added the -use_obl_origin option running:

```
Dimon -infile_prefix IM -gert_create_dataset -use_obl_origin
```

but I still get the same error. How can I deal with this issue?

Comment: Hi Marta, if you found a work-around on this issue don't hold back to answer your own question! +1

Comment: It looks like it's telling you to use `-max_images`